# Getting the contents of more than one DB table in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying make an endpoint to get the content of two independent tables from my DB using Spring but I've got no idea how to do it.

In my interface I have the following:

```
List<TableName> findByTitleContains(String title);
```

How do I add an extra List?

In my Controller I have:

```
public ControllerName(InterfaceName interfaceName) {
        this.interfaceName = interfaceName;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<TableName> findAll(){
        var variableName = interfaceName.findAll();
        return variableName;
```

I'm sorry if this was badly explained but I'm very new to both Java and Spring.

Comment: Can you change the interface method `findByTitleContains` to return a map or a wrapper class?

Comment: Are the tables on the same db, such that you can union the two select statements? Alternatively, within the interfaceImpl method, could you not hit the dao twice (once per table) into two separate lists, and then combine them before returning? Or, do you need to keep the two lists entirely separate? In that case, aksappy prob has the better route

Comment: Yes, they are in the same DB. I managed to do it by using @SecondaryTable. But thanks for the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

create a hashmap , put Table a list and table b list inside a hashmap and return hashmap .